# Jquery to get or retrieve data from meta tags

Tags: jquery, meta-tags

Meta tag is unnamed. I'm unable to get its content info

I have tried for meta tag with name, description and it worked. I tried to call all meta without specifying name and description. But it was hard to locate the data i was searching for due to lot of metas. I need to filter with 'itemprop'.

```
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://examples.com/">
var desc = $('meta').attr('content', 'value');
console.log(desc);
//This returned all metas with attr content
// I wish to filter meta which has itemprop and its value is url
```

output :- https://examples.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through them all and check `itemprop`, example:

```js
$('meta').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('itemprop') == "url") {
      console.log($(this).attr("content"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta itemprop="not found" content="https://examples.com/">
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://examples.com/">
<meta itemprop="test" content="https://examples.com/">
```

Or you can use attribute filter:

```js
console.log($("meta[itemprop='url']").attr("content"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta itemprop="not found" content="https://examples.com/">
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://examples.com/">
<meta itemprop="test" content="https://examples.com/">
```

Comment: Good Morning buddy. Great! it actually worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. Have a great day..

Answer (score 0):

Use followoing in case

- To set the attribute value : $('meta').attr('content', 'value');
- To get the attribute value : $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
- To filter base on attribute (if itemp prop is present in meta tag) : $('meta[itemprop]')

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBMk.png)

Thank you for reading

Comment: Please edit your post with proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make it more easily readable.

Comment: No link was provided by OP.  "examples.com" is an example, not a link